# NSNumberFormatter grouping

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I would like to format string with numbers to look like this: `XX XX XX` (e.g. `12 34 56`)

I'm using `NSNumberFormatter` with grouping separator:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
formatter.groupingSize = 2
formatter.groupingSeparator = " "
if let number = Int(theText.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")) {
       let numberToFormat = NSNumber(integer:number)
       textField.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberToFormat)
}
```

This will work fine, if you enter number `123456` - it is formatted to `12 34 56`

I use this inside `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method so it should format number as you type. Grouping separator defines numbers are grouped by `groupingSize` value from right side, so when you type in `123456` this is how text changes:

```
1
12
1 23
12 34
1 23 45
12 34 45
```

and I would like to format it as following:

```
1
12
12 3
12 34
12 34 5
12 34 56
```

Is it possible to define from which side grouping separator groups numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you have to covert to `Int`, how about add a "0" at the end? Then remove the last "0".

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
formatter.groupingSize = 2
formatter.groupingSeparator = " "

var str = "12345"
if str.characters.count % 2 != 0 {
    str += "0"
}
if let number = Int(str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")) {
    let numberToFormat = NSNumber(integer:number)
    formatter.stringFromNumber(numberToFormat)
}
```

Another solution:

```
let string = "12345"

var results = [String]()
for index in 0 ..< string.characters.count-1 {
    if index % 2 == 0 {
        let range = NSRange(location: index, length: 2)
        results.append((string as NSString).substringWithRange(range))
    }
}

if string.characters.count % 2 != 0 {
    let last = (string as NSString).substringFromIndex(string.characters.count-1)
    results.append(last)
}
```

Comment: it is great idea to add 0 at end and remove it afterwards, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Swit 4**

You have to use the delegate of UITextField : `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)`

this works fine :

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == YourTextField {
        if (textField.text?.count)! < 8 {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
            formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB") as Locale?
            formatter.groupingSize = 2
            formatter.groupingSeparator = "-" // if you want the format XX-XX-XX
            // Uses the grouping separator corresponding
            if let groupingSeparator = formatter.groupingSeparator {

                if string == groupingSeparator {
                    return true
                }
                if let textWithoutGroupingSeparator = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: groupingSeparator, with: "") {
                    var totalTextWithoutGroupingSeparators = textWithoutGroupingSeparator + string
                    if string == "" { // pressed Backspace key
                        totalTextWithoutGroupingSeparators.characters.removeLast()
                    }
                    if let numberWithoutGroupingSeparator = formatter.number(from: totalTextWithoutGroupingSeparators),
                        let formattedText = formatter.string(from: numberWithoutGroupingSeparator) {
                        print(numberWithoutGroupingSeparator)
                        numberWithoutGroupingSeparators = String(format: "%@", numberWithoutGroupingSeparator)
                        textField.text = formattedText
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
        return true

}
```